# how to convert jquery ajax if else statement to switch statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i write a jquery ajax script to load pages dynamically by ajax without reloading the page. below is my navigation menu that has 5 links in it.

```
 <nav>
 <ul id='menu' class="menu-items">
 <li><a href="#Browse_Page1" class="albums active" id="page1-link"><i class="arcd-archive"></i></br>Browse</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_albums_Page1" class="pages" id="page2-link"><i class="arcd-music97"></i></br>Top albums</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_artists_Page1" class="albums" id="page3-link"><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_lists_Page1" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-numbered8"></i></br>Top lists</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Charts_Page1" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-rising9"></i></br>Charts</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

and this is the jquery ajax that loads first two pages of the navigation menu "#Browse_Page1" "#Top_albums_Page1" respectively.

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
 $('header nav a').on('click', function() {
 var linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
 if(linkClicked.indexOf('Browse_Page') == true)
 {
     var $Browse_PageRoot = linkClicked.replace('#Browse_Page', '');
     if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
 $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");}
 $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load.php",
        data: 'Browse_Page='+$Browse_PageRoot,

        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#main-content').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
            }
        }

      });
     }
    else
    {
   var $Top_albums_PageRoot = linkClicked.replace('#Top_albums_Page',  ''); 
     if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");} 
    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');      
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load2.php",
            data: 'Top_albums_Page='+$Top_albums_PageRoot,

            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg){

                if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                {
                    $('#main-content').html(msg);
                    $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                    $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
                }
            }            
          });
       }

     });

   });
  </script>
```

finally these are two php files that used by above jquery ajax function     "load.php" and "load2.php"

```
  <!--load.php-->
  <?php
  if(!$_POST['Browse_Page']) ;
  $page = (int)$_POST['Browse_Page'];
  if(file_exists('Browse/Browse_Page'.$page.'.html'))
  echo file_get_contents('Browse/Browse_Page'.$page.'.html');
  else echo 'There is no such page!';
  ?>

  <!--load2.php-->
  <?php
  if(!$_POST['Top_albums_Page']) die("0");
  $page = (int)$_POST['Top_albums_Page'];
  if(file_exists('Top-albums/Top_albums_Page'.$page.'.html'))
  echo file_get_contents('Top-albums/Top_albums_Page'.$page.'.html');
  else echo 'There is no such page!';
  ?>
```

and my site folders structure as follows.

- Browse
- Top-albums
- Top-artists
- Top-lists
- Charts

so my problem is that as i said above jquery ajax function loads two different pages from two different directories and it works fine but i have 5 page links in nav menu and all pages are in different directories, 5 different directories! but this function only supports two directories.
i tried it to add more if else statements to full fill my desire but it didn't work. since i am new to jquery maybe i am doing it wrongly!
or is there any way to convert it to switch statement?
any help will greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually quite horrible, you should strive to send data that can be easily read and figured out on the serverside, without the need to repeat the code for each dataset.

In other words, rewrite the javascript to something like this

```
$(function () {
    $('header nav a').on('click', function () {
        var linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
        var data = {
            page      : linkClicked.replace(/\D/g, ''),
            directory : linkClicked.replace(/(_Page(.*)|#)/g,'')
        }

        $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');

        $.post('load.php', data, function(msg) {
            $('#main-content').html(msg);
            $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
        }, 'html');
    });
});
```

Now you're sending data that looks something like

```
{
    page      : "1",
    directory : "Browse"
}
```

And on the serverside, you'd do the switching to get the content in one single PHP file

```
<?php

    $page = filter_var( $_POST['page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $dir  = filter_var( $_POST['directory'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if ( $page !== false && $dir !== false ) {

        $link = $dir . '/' . $dir . '_Page' . $page . '.html';

        if ( file_exists( $link ) ) {
            echo file_get_contents( $link );
        } else {
            echo 'There is no such page!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your kind support! can you describe this for me because i really don't understood the logic. `page      : linkClicked.replace(/\D/g, ''),
            directory : linkClicked.replace(/(_Page(.*)|#)/g,'')` the does mean by`(/\D/g, ''),` and `(_Page(.*)|#)/g,` and where i hould add my pages links?

Comment: It's an object, containing keys and values, and the values are strings created from the href. Why not just console.log `data` and see what it contains.

Comment: ok thanks for reply! one last thing where to put this chunk of code? in the script or php file? `{
    page      : "1",
    directory : "Browse"
}`

Comment: You don't put it anywhere, it's just an example of how the data you're now sending looks like.

Comment: can you please tell me why it gives this error? `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in Z:\AMR\load.php on line 4` and no page loaded! how to correct it? please i am waiting for your guideline. thanks

Comment: ok i correct the error on line 4 there was an extra closing square bracket but now its only loads `"#Browse_Page1"` and `"#Charts_Page1"` pages rest of three still not loading! please help me.............please

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here it goes, I made some changes with explanations in the code comments.

Add a `data` attribute for the page and another one for the directory, ex. 'data-page' and 'data-dir' to each `a` element like so

```
<nav>
<ul id='menu' class="menu-items">
<li><a href="#Browse_Page1" data-page="1" data-dir="Browse" class="albums active" id="page1-link"><i class="arcd-archive"></i></br>Browse</a></li>
<li><a href="#Top_albums_Page1" data-page="2" data-dir="Top-albums" class="pages" id="page2-link"><i class="arcd-music97"></i></br>Top albums</a></li>
<li><a href="#Top_artists_Page1" data-page="3" data-dir="Top-artists" class="albums" id="page3-link"><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
<li><a href="#Top_lists_Page1" data-page="4" data-dir="Top-lists" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-numbered8"></i></br>Top lists</a></li>
<li><a href="#Charts_Page1" data-page="5" data-dir="Charts" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-rising9"></i></br>Charts</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Change the `onclick` function so that it picks up the page from the `data` attribute and send the `ajax` request only to one `php` script.
I also moved the 'make active' logic to a function.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('nav ul#menu a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // var linkClicked = $(this).data('page'); not using this anymore
        var pagevar = $(this).data('page');
        var dirvar = $(this).data('dir');
        // make the clicked link active, the rest of them inactive, show the loading element
        makeActive($(this));

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load.php",
            data: {page:pagevar,dir:dirvar},
            success: function(msg){
                if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
                    $('#main-content').html(msg);
                    $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                    $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
    });

function makeActive(link){
    var ul = $(link).parent().parent();
    $('a',ul).removeClass("active");
    $(link).addClass("active");
    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
}

});
</script>
```

Finally make your `php` script handle any page request and I would like to stress out the importance of defining a whitelist of acceptable values, else you are opening yourself to large range local file include vulnerabilities.

load.php

```
// define your acceptable values for pages to avoid pains
$pages = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$directories = array("Browse","Top-albums","Top-artists","Top-lists","Charts");

if ((isset($_POST['page']) and in_array($_POST['page'],$pages)) and (isset($_POST['dir']) and in_array($_POST['dir'],$directories))  ){
    if(file_exists($_POST['dir'] . '/Browse_Page'.$_POST['page'].'.html'))
        echo file_get_contents('Browse/Browse_Page'.$_POST['page'].'.html');
}
else echo 'There is no such page!';
```

Comment: do i need to add more if else statements in load.php for other pages?

Comment: nope, the `if` clause is generic, it will check for any file

Comment: thanks for reply! but as said in my question all these pages are in different directories does it matter or it still works?

Comment: i missed that part, but you can use @adeneo's solution which works with different directories

Comment: can you please re edit it so it able work with different directories! i will really appreciated that since i am new to javascript i couldn't do it my self

Comment: edited the answer to cover for pages as well as directories

Comment: thanks you very very very much sir! but still yet to try let see what happens

Comment: sorry! i tested and its comes with this error `Notice: Undefined variable: page in Z:\AMR\load.php on line 10

Warning: file_get_contents(../Browse/Browse_Page.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\AMR\load.php on line 10` can you solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83050/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-arcade).

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your PHP code, it doesn't seem like it's doing much except reading content from static HTML files. jQuery has a useful "load" function if you simply want to load HTML content.

Also, you can leverage HTML5 data attributes to store the paths to the HTML content files you want to pull into your page. I see that one of the answers to your question is using this approach, too. That said, I recommend a simpler approach to the problem by simply including the entire relative file path to the HTML content. That way, you have more flexibility in terms of how your content file structure gets set up and maintained.

I'm assuming that you don't have any special security requirements. Your question doesn't mention any, nor does your code imply such a need.

Here's the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function($) {

      $(function() {
        $("header nav a").click(function() {
          var $this = $(this),
              loadFrom = $this.data("navigate-to"),
              fadeSpeed = 1000;

          $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
          $this.addClass("active");

          $("#loading").fadeIn(fadeSpeed, function() {
            $("#main-content").load(loadFrom, function(res, status, xhr) {
                if(status=="error") {
                  $("#main-content").html("Content couldn't be loaded.");
                }
            });
            $(this).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
          });

        });
      });

    })(jQuery);

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <li><a href="#browse-page-1" data-navigate-to="/browse/page1.html" class="albums active">Browse</a></li>
        <li><a href="#top-albums-page-1" data-navigate-to="/top_albums/page1.html"  class="albums">Top Albums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#top-artists-page-1" data-navigate-to="/top_artists/page1.html" class="albums">Top Artists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#charts-page-1" data-navigate-to="/charts/page1.html" class="albums">Charts</a></li>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none;">
      <p>
        Loading...
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your support and ans but sorry to say i tried this but it doesn't working! please check it to make sure is everything is ok? 2nd as you mentioned security can you please tell me how vulnerable is this code is? is this code going to shows my folder structure or anything serious plz tell me about that and finally how to make it better? i mean security friendly. thanks.

Comment: I tested the example prior to posting it. It's possible that there's some difference in how you've configured your site that is at the root of the problem you're having. If you run my example through a local web server, it should work for you so long as you do have your HTML files located in the directory paths that reflect what is in the data-navigate-to attributes of the anchor tags in the navigation.

Comment: In terms of security, I saw that you're using PHP to serve up page content. So I wasn't sure whether you were going to implement some form of authentication for your end users to see page content. If not, then using PHP is not really necessary UNLESS you're going to be implementing some form of template system for your page content. However, from your example, I have the impression that you aren't doing this either. That said, using PHP appears, from your example code, to be just an extra layer that you don't seem to need.